# GNU inline assembly optimisation

Tags: optimization, gcc, x86-64, inline-assembly, icc

I am trying to write a small library for highly optimised x86-64 bit operation code and am fiddling with inline asm.

While testing this particular case has caught my attention:

```
unsigned long test = 0;
unsigned long bsr;

// bit test and set 39th bit
__asm__ ("btsq\t%1, %0 " : "+rm" (test) : "rJ" (39) );

// bit scan reverse (get most significant bit id)
__asm__ ("bsrq\t%1, %0" : "=r" (bsr) : "rm" (test) );

printf("test = %lu, bsr = %d\n", test, bsr);
```

compiles and runs fine in both gcc and icc, but when I inspect the assembly I get differences

`gcc -S -fverbose-asm -std=gnu99 -O3`

```
movq    $0, -8(%rbp)
## InlineAsm Start
btsq    $39, -8(%rbp) 
## InlineAsm End
movq    -8(%rbp), %rax
movq    %rax, -16(%rbp)
## InlineAsm Start
bsrq    -16(%rbp), %rdx
## InlineAsm End
movq    -8(%rbp), %rsi
leaq    L_.str(%rip), %rdi
xorb    %al, %al
callq   _printf
```

I am wondering why so complicated? I am writing high performance code in which the number of instructions is critical. I am especially wondering why gcc makes a copy of my variable `test` before passing it to the second inline asm?

Same code compiled with icc gives far better results:

```
    xorl      %esi, %esi                                    # test = 0
    movl      $.L_2__STRING.0, %edi                         # has something to do with printf
    orl       $32832, (%rsp)                                # part of function initiation
    xorl      %eax, %eax                                    # has something to do with printf
    ldmxcsr   (%rsp)                                        # part of function initiation
    btsq      $39, %rsi                                     #106.0
    bsrq      %rsi, %rdx                                    #109.0
    call      printf                                        #111.2
```

despite the fact that gcc decides to keep my variables on the stack rather then in registers, what I do not understand is why make a copy of `test` before passing it to the second asm?
If I put `test` in as an input/output variable in the second asm

`__asm__ ("bsrq\t%1, %0" : "=r" (bsr) , "+rm" (test) );`

then those lines disappear.

```
movq    $0, -8(%rbp)
## InlineAsm Start
btsq    $39, -8(%rbp) 
## InlineAsm End
## InlineAsm Start
bsrq    -8(%rbp), %rdx
## InlineAsm End
movq    -8(%rbp), %rsi
leaq    L_.str(%rip), %rdi
xorb    %al, %al
callq   _printf
```

Is this gcc screwed up optimisation or am I missing some vital compiler switches? I do have icc for my production system, but if I decide to distribute the source code at some point then it will have to be able to compile with gcc too.

compilers used:

gcc version 4.2.1 (Based on Apple Inc. build 5658) (LLVM build 2336.1.00)

icc Version 12.0.2

Comment: Why not just use the standard intrinsics for these operations ? That way the compiler does most of the work for you (and it will probably do a better job too).

Comment: Well, first of all these are not the only instructions that I intend to use, it's just examples.
gcc has intrinsics for most of them, icc is not that fortunately blessed with intrinsics and I have a good 20-30% performance increase from just compiling with icc.

Comment: OK - but unless there is something specific that can't be done via intrinsics I still believe that the compiler will do a better job than you if you let it.

Comment: Apart from the fact that I am not looking for compiler intrinsics (I know where to find them) they produce far more instructions then I would use and different results in different compilers.
`__builtin_clzll(0)` is 64 when compiled with gcc and 63 in icc.


My question in this topic is on how to optimise embedment of inline asm.

Comment: Can you please provide a _complete_ source example that makes gcc emit the assembler code you've shown ? I've tried embedding your snippet into a `main()` and compiling it with various gcc versions starting at 3.2.3 up to 4.7.2, and none reproduces the code which puts `test` in the stack at `-O3` opt level. Please give more context.

Comment: This is the whole body of my `main()`. It really seems to be an issue with the Apple dev kit gcc, because gcc on our Linux cluster does not have this problem. See my comment below.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've tried your example on Linux like this (making it "evil" by forcing a stack ref/loc for `test` through using `&test` in the `printf`:):

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    unsigned long test = 0;
    unsigned long bsr;
// bit test and set 39th bit
    asm ("btsq\t%1, %0 " : "+rm" (test) : "rJ" (39) );
// bit scan reverse (get most significant bit id)
    asm ("bsrq\t%1, %0" : "=r" (bsr) : "rm" (test) );
    printf("test = %lu, bsr = %d, &test = %p\n", test, bsr, &test);
    return 0;
}
```

and compiled it with various versions of `gcc -O3` ... to the following results:

```
code generated                                                     gcc version
================================================================================
  400630:       48 83 ec 18             sub    $0x18,%rsp          4.7.2,
  400634:       31 c0                   xor    %eax,%eax           4.6.2,
  400636:       bf 50 07 40 00          mov    $0x400750,%edi      4.4.6
  40063b:       48 8d 4c 24 08          lea    0x8(%rsp),%rcx
  400640:       48 0f ba e8 27          bts    $0x27,%rax
  400645:       48 89 44 24 08          mov    %rax,0x8(%rsp)
  40064a:       48 89 c6                mov    %rax,%rsi
  40064d:       48 0f bd d0             bsr    %rax,%rdx
  400651:       31 c0                   xor    %eax,%eax
  400653:       e8 68 fe ff ff          callq  4004c0 
[ ... ]
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  4004f0:       48 83 ec 18             sub    $0x18,%rsp          4.1
  4004f4:       31 c0                   xor    %eax,%eax
  4004f6:       bf 28 06 40 00          mov    $0x400628,%edi
  4004fb:       48 8d 4c 24 10          lea    0x10(%rsp),%rcx
  400500:       48 c7 44 24 10 00 00 00 00      movq   $0x0,0x10(%rsp)
  400509:       48 0f ba e8 27          bts    $0x27,%rax
  40050e:       48 89 44 24 10          mov    %rax,0x10(%rsp)
  400513:       48 89 c6                mov    %rax,%rsi
  400516:       48 0f bd d0             bsr    %rax,%rdx
  40051a:       31 c0                   xor    %eax,%eax
  40051c:       e8 c7 fe ff ff          callq  4003e8 
[ ... ]
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  400500:       48 83 ec 08             sub    $0x8,%rsp           3.4.5
  400504:       bf 30 06 40 00          mov    $0x400630,%edi
  400509:       31 c0                   xor    %eax,%eax
  40050b:       48 c7 04 24 00 00 00 00         movq   $0x0,(%rsp)
  400513:       48 89 e1                mov    %rsp,%rcx
  400516:       48 0f ba 2c 24 27       btsq   $0x27,(%rsp)
  40051c:       48 8b 34 24             mov    (%rsp),%rsi
  400520:       48 0f bd 14 24          bsr    (%rsp),%rdx
  400525:       e8 fe fe ff ff          callq  400428 
[ ... ]
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  4004e0:       48 83 ec 08             sub    $0x8,%rsp           3.2.3
  4004e4:       bf 10 06 40 00          mov    $0x400610,%edi
  4004e9:       31 c0                   xor    %eax,%eax
  4004eb:       48 c7 04 24 00 00 00 00         movq   $0x0,(%rsp)
  4004f3:       48 0f ba 2c 24 27       btsq   $0x27,(%rsp)
  4004f9:       48 8b 34 24             mov    (%rsp),%rsi
  4004fd:       48 89 e1                mov    %rsp,%rcx
  400500:       48 0f bd 14 24          bsr    (%rsp),%rdx
  400505:       e8 ee fe ff ff          callq  4003f8 
[ ... ]
```

and while there's a significant difference in the created code (including whether the `bsr` acceesses `test` as register or memory), none of the tested revs recreate the assembly that you've shown. I'd suspect a bug in the 4.2.x version you used on MacOSX, but then I don't have either your testcase nor that specific compiler version available.

**Edit:** The code above is obviously different in the sense that it forces `test` into the stack; if that is *not* done, then all "plain" gcc versions I've tested do a direct pair `bts $39, %rsi` / `bsr %rsi, %rdx`.

I have found, though, that `clang` creates different code there:

```
 140:   50                      push   %rax
 141:   48 c7 04 24 00 00 00 00         movq   $0x0,(%rsp)
 149:   31 f6                   xor    %esi,%esi
 14b:   48 0f ba ee 27          bts    $0x27,%rsi
 150:   48 89 34 24             mov    %rsi,(%rsp)
 154:   48 0f bd d6             bsr    %rsi,%rdx
 158:   bf 00 00 00 00          mov    $0x0,%edi
 15d:   30 c0                   xor    %al,%al
 15f:   e8 00 00 00 00          callq  printf@plt>
```

so the difference seems to be indeed between the code generators of clang/llvm and "gcc proper".

Comment: Yeah, it seems to be a weird apple dev kit gcc. I also tried to compile it on our cluster with gcc instead and I get code very similar to what icc produces.
I believe the optimizer switch I am looking for is `-fforward-propagate` which is not even part of the apple dev kit gcc.
I will let this problem rest knowing that my macbook pro is not the production system.